# How to show differences between two univariate datasets graphically?

Tags: data-visualization, matlab, gnuplot

I have two different columns of data which are recorded in different configurations and **I want to show the users that these two records varie** (data is time in seconds). The dataset is not of the same size as shown below. The end users are all experienced people in stats and math.  My question is how can I plot a graph (which kind of(?)) easily.
First dataset:

```
0.000223
0.000206
0.000223
0.000193
0.001321
0.000223
...
```

Second dataset:

```
0.076975003
0.076724999
0.076600999
0.0766
0.050742
0.000397
0.000642
0.000522
0.000772
0.000522
0.076725997
0.158800006
0.159801006
0.159426004
...
```

Some of the graphs I came across: boxplot, meantime.

Comment: Could you clarify what precisely are those measurements (time to perform a given task?) and what is the data structure, that is what are the different conditions and what's the number of records? Also you added two different tags? Are you expecting two distinct solutions, in Matlab and Gnuplot?

Comment: @chl, these are the arrival times of the packets measured in our network. the two dataset is not big, but the sizes are different as mentioned. i just want to show the differences of these time measurements in the same plot. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try a q-q plot if you have enough data;

```
%make fake data;
x1 = randn(1000,1) .^ 2;x2 = (1.3 * randn(2000,1)).^2;
%which quantiles?
alphas = linspace(0,1,100);alphas = alphas(2:end-1);
q1 = interp1(linspace(0,1,numel(x1)),sort(x1),alphas,'linear');
q2 = interp1(linspace(0,1,numel(x2)),sort(x2),alphas,'linear');
scatter(q1,q2)
set(gca(),'XScale','log');set(gca(),'YScale','log');
xyline = [min(min(q1),min(q2)),max(max(q1),max(q2))];
hold on;
plot(xyline,xyline,'r-');
```

[image: with x=y line added]

Adding a linear fit with stock matlab tools is not as simple as a one-liner, regrettably...

Comment: For reference you might want to add the line y=x, not a linear fit.  This is more relevant to the need to demonstrate the two datasets differ.

Comment: @whuber: good catch; my mistake;

Answer (score 2):

Rather than a boxplot, I'd use a strip chart, since both data sets are small and it will be easy to see each data point.

Comment: Not sure that sample size will not be an issue, as the OP specified that "The dataset is not in same size as shown below" -- stripchart with 10^6 points will be messy :)

Comment: i dont have any y axis, only the time measurements belong to networks which varies...

Comment: @berkay Ah so stripchart may make sense in this case! You can even superimpose individual (jittered) points onto a boxplot for each series of measurement. Either way, your y-axis = your measurement units, the x-axis = your two groups or a dummy variable coding them.

Comment: @chl Yes, jittering works well: good suggestion.

Comment: @chi ... ooops, I missed that.  Yeah, a strip chart with a lot of data would be a mess